# How to open a project in eclipse ADT and automatically import LIbrary Projects dependencies

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Just started developing android apps using Eclipse ADT. I've never used Eclipse before so not sure if this is an ADT specific question or an eclipse question.

So I started by creating a new project. I have another project that I would like to use as a project library, so I copied that into the `libs` folder. My project now looks something like this

```
MyApp
  libs
    OtherProject
  res
  src
  ...
```

I then imported the `OtherProject` as an existing project and set it as a library. Now my package explorer contains two projects: MyApp, and OtherProject

I then right-clicked --> Properties on my main project, went to Android, and then added the other project as a library.

Everything works.

I pushed it to a repository and then cloned it to a separate folder to verify that everything still works.

Now, I'm not sure what to do here to open the project, so I went and imported the newly checked out project, but it says its missing the OtherProject dependency, and I can see that it wasn't automatically added to the package explorer.

What is the proper way to open a project?

Comment: this 'seperate folder' that you cloned, is it in the eclipse workspace?

Comment: @ipohfly yes, I copied it to libs and then imported it into the workspace and added it as a library to MyApp. I did it that way so that when I push it to repo others can download it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue but I solved it by importing both the library project and other project into same work space (Use the check box to add the copy to work space while importing)

Comment: is that from the perspective of someone checking out a project? Would it be correct for me to assume that if I have several project library dependencies, then anyone that wishes to set it up on their own machine would need to manually import all of those projects as well?

Answer (score 0):

You dont copy projects to libs folder. It is for jar files only. Import the project you wantto use as a library into eclipse as any other project (copy project to workspace optional) and then add the imported project as a library for your project.

Comment: that is what I had initially done, but the library wasn't being automatically added to the workspace when I checked out a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the artifact of the build for your `OtherProject` will give, but i'll assume it's a jar file.

You can copy the jar into the `libs` folder of your `MyApp` project and configure it in your build path. Once the build is successful, add the jar file to your source control (by right click on the file -> Team -> Add to Source Control) and check in BOTH the jar file and the project .classpath file (you should see them in your check in dialog).

Once this is done, you can checkout a new copy of the project, and verify that the libs folder does contains the jar and the build path is correct. Then you should be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oops, it's actually called "[library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html)". So basically an unpacked project I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell Eclipse to automatically import the library project as an Eclipse project when you import the main project. You will always need to import the main project, then import the library project.